# How can I display data in an infobox in bing maps pulling the data from a DB in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bing-maps

I'm trying to pull data from a db including images and display it in an infobox in bing maps. Do I need to do a custom infobox? Thanks for everyone's help. I will be using asp.net MVC for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need custom HTML for your infobox. There are a couple of options for this. One option is to use the built in Infobox control and set it's HTML content. This wipes out the whole style of the infobox so a bit more work is required. I have a blog post on how to handle this here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/simple-custom-infoboxes-in-bing-maps-v7/

Another option is to use the Custom Infobox module I created for Bing Maps a while back. It gives you a lot more options when it comes to customizing infoboxes: http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Infobox%20Control